# Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax (the new One)

Tags: mysql

I got this error message from my MySQL code. But I don't know where is my fault..
Here's my code:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `kp`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getAllUmurPegawai`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllUmurPegawai`()

BEGIN

    DECLARE currdate INT;
    DECLARE birthdate INT;
    DECLARE numRows INT;
    DECLARE numIteration INT;
    DECLARE tempMonth INT;

    SET numRows = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pegawai;
    SET numIteration = 1;
    WHILE numIteration <= numRows DO
        SET currdate = (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE));    
        SET birthdate = (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT TGL_LAHIR FROM pegawai WHERE INDEXING = numIteration)));
        SET umur = currdate - birthdate;
        SET tempMonth = SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT TGL_LAHIR FROM pegawai WHERE INDEXING = numIteration));
        IF umur < 56 THEN
            INSERT INTO pegawai(STATUS_PEGAWAI,BULAN_PENSIUN(JIKA_SUDAH)) VALUES('Belum Pensiun',0);
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO pegawai(STATUS_PEGAWAI,BULAN_PENSIUN(JIKA_SUDAH)) VALUES('Pensiun',tempMonth);
        END IF;
        SET numIteration = numIteration + 1;
    END WHILE;  
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and i get this error message:

```
Query : CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllUmurPegawai`() BEGIN DECLARE currdate INT; DECLARE birthdate INT; DECLARE num...

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pegawai;
SET numIteration = 1;

WHILE numIteration <= numR' at line 8
```

How can i solve this problem? Best Answer will be appreciated :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a `SELECT` query as an expression you have to put it in parentheses:

```
SET numRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pegawai);
```

You did it correctly when you were setting `currDate` and `birthdate`, but you forgot the parentheses on this line.